# Vuejs-pdf print

Tags: vue.js, pdf, printing

I'm using vuejs-pdf to print some pages of my pdf and the print is not show the characters :

[image]

that's the code i'm using :

```
<button @click="$refs.myPdfComponent.print(100,pages)">Print </button>
<pdf v-for="i in pages" :key="i" ref="newpdf"  :src="'pdf/'+src" :page="i"  class="rounded border 
  border-info mb-4" :rotate="rotate" @progress="loadedRatio = $event" @error="error" @num-pages="numPages = $event" @link-clicked="page = $event" > </pdf>
```

and the pdf i'm printing is myPdfComponent the newpdf is the only the pages i need :

```
<pdf v-if="show" ref="myPdfComponent" class="rounded border border-info mb-4" :src="'pdf/'+src" 
:page="page" :rotate="rotate" @progress="loadedRatio = $event" @error="error" @num-pages="numPages = 
$event" @link-clicked="page = $event"></pdf>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the vue-pdf plugin directory **node_modules/vue-pdf/src/pdfjsWrapper.js**
and replace

```js
import { PDFLinkService } from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/web/pdf_viewer';

var pendingOperation = Promise.resolve();

export default function(PDFJS) {

    function isPDFDocumentLoadingTask(obj) {

        return typeof(obj) === 'object' && obj !== null && obj.__PDFDocumentLoadingTask === true;
        // or: return obj.constructor.name === 'PDFDocumentLoadingTask';
    }

    function createLoadingTask(src, options) {

        var source;
        if ( typeof(src) === 'string' )
            source = { url: src };
        else if ( src instanceof Uint8Array )
            source = { data: src };
        else if ( typeof(src) === 'object' && src !== null )
            source = Object.assign({}, src);
        else
            throw new TypeError('invalid src type');

        // source.verbosity = PDFJS.VerbosityLevel.INFOS;
        // source.pdfBug = true;
        // source.stopAtErrors = true;

        if ( options && options.withCredentials )
            source.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;

        var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(source);
        loadingTask.__PDFDocumentLoadingTask = true; // since PDFDocumentLoadingTask is not public

        if ( options && options.onPassword )
            loadingTask.onPassword = options.onPassword;

        if ( options && options.onProgress )
            loadingTask.onProgress = options.onProgress;

        return loadingTask;
    }


    function PDFJSWrapper(canvasElt, annotationLayerElt, emitEvent) {

        var pdfDoc = null;
        var pdfPage = null;
        var pdfRender = null;
        var canceling = false;

        canvasElt.getContext('2d').save();

        function clearCanvas() {

            canvasElt.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvasElt.width, canvasElt.height);
        }

        function clearAnnotations() {

            while ( annotationLayerElt.firstChild )
                annotationLayerElt.removeChild(annotationLayerElt.firstChild);
        }

        this.destroy = function() {

            if ( pdfDoc === null )
                return;

            // Aborts all network requests and destroys worker.
            pendingOperation = pdfDoc.destroy();
            pdfDoc = null;
        }

        this.getResolutionScale = function() {

            return canvasElt.offsetWidth / canvasElt.width;
        }

        this.printPage = function(dpi, pageNumberOnly) {

            if ( pdfPage === null )
                return;

            // 1in == 72pt
            // 1in == 96px
            var PRINT_RESOLUTION = dpi === undefined ? 150 : dpi;
            var PRINT_UNITS = PRINT_RESOLUTION / 72.0;
            var CSS_UNITS = 96.0 / 72.0;

            /*var iframeElt = document.createElement('iframe');

            function removeIframe() {

                iframeElt.parentNode.removeChild(iframeElt);
            }*/
            
            var printContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
            printContainerElement.setAttribute('id', 'print-container')
            
            function removePrintContainer() {
                printContainerElement.parentNode.removeChild(printContainerElement);
            }

            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
/*
                iframeElt.frameBorder = '0';
                iframeElt.scrolling = 'no';
                iframeElt.width = '0px;'
                iframeElt.height = '0px;'
                iframeElt.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0';

                iframeElt.onload = function() {

                    resolve(this.contentWindow);
                }

                window.document.body.appendChild(iframeElt);*/
                
                printContainerElement.frameBorder = '0';
                printContainerElement.scrolling = 'no';
                printContainerElement.width = '0px;'
                printContainerElement.height = '0px;'
                printContainerElement.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0';

                window.document.body.appendChild(printContainerElement);
                resolve(window)
            })
            .then(function(win) {

                win.document.title = '';

                return pdfDoc.getPage(1)
                .then(function(page) {

                    var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
                    //win.document.head.appendChild(win.document.createElement('style')).textContent =
                    printContainerElement.appendChild(win.document.createElement('style')).textContent =
                        '@supports ((size:A4) and (size:1pt 1pt)) {' +
                            '@page { margin: 1pt; size: ' + ((viewport.width * PRINT_UNITS) / CSS_UNITS) + 'pt ' + ((viewport.height * PRINT_UNITS) / CSS_UNITS) + 'pt; }' +
                        '}' +
                        
                        '#print-canvas { display: none }' +

                        '@media print {' +
                                'body { margin: 0 }' +
                            'canvas { page-break-before: avoid; page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid }' +
                        '#print-canvas { page-break-before: avoid; page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid; display: block }' +
                        'body > *:not(#print-container) { display: none; }' +
                        '}'+

                        '@media screen {' +
                            'body { margin: 0 }' +
                        '}'+

                        ''
                    return win;
                })
            })
            .then(function(win) {

                var allPages = [];

                for ( var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= pdfDoc.numPages; ++pageNumber ) {

                    if ( pageNumberOnly !== undefined && pageNumberOnly.indexOf(pageNumber) === -1 )
                        continue;

                    allPages.push(
                        pdfDoc.getPage(pageNumber)
                        .then(function(page) {

                            var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });

                            //var printCanvasElt = win.document.body.appendChild(win.document.createElement('canvas'));
                            var printCanvasElt = printContainerElement.appendChild(win.document.createElement('canvas'));
                            printCanvasElt.setAttribute('id', 'print-canvas')
                            
                            printCanvasElt.width = (viewport.width * PRINT_UNITS);
                            printCanvasElt.height = (viewport.height * PRINT_UNITS);

                            return page.render({
                                canvasContext: printCanvasElt.getContext('2d'),
                                transform: [ // Additional transform, applied just before viewport transform.
                                    PRINT_UNITS, 0, 0,
                                    PRINT_UNITS, 0, 0
                                ],
                                viewport: viewport,
                                intent: 'print'
                            }).promise;
                        })
                    );
                }

                Promise.all(allPages)
                .then(function() {

                    win.focus(); // Required for IE
                    if (win.document.queryCommandSupported('print')) {
                        win.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
                        } else {
                        win.print();
                      }
                    removePrintContainer();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {

                    removePrintContainer();
                    emitEvent('error', err);
                })
            })
        }

        this.renderPage = function(rotate) {
            if ( pdfRender !== null ) {

                if ( canceling )
                    return;
                canceling = true;
                pdfRender.cancel();
                return;
            }

            if ( pdfPage === null )
                return;

            var pageRotate = (pdfPage.rotate === undefined ? 0 : pdfPage.rotate) + (rotate === undefined ? 0 : rotate);

            var scale = canvasElt.offsetWidth / pdfPage.getViewport({ scale: 1 }).width * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
            var viewport = pdfPage.getViewport({ scale: scale, rotation:pageRotate });

            emitEvent('page-size', viewport.width, viewport.height, scale);

            canvasElt.width = viewport.width;
            canvasElt.height = viewport.height;

            pdfRender = pdfPage.render({
                canvasContext: canvasElt.getContext('2d'),
                viewport: viewport
            });

            annotationLayerElt.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            clearAnnotations();

            var viewer = {
                scrollPageIntoView: function(params) {
                    emitEvent('link-clicked', params.pageNumber)
                },
            };

            var linkService = new PDFLinkService();
            linkService.setDocument(pdfDoc);
            linkService.setViewer(viewer);

            pendingOperation = pendingOperation.then(function() {

                var getAnnotationsOperation =
                pdfPage.getAnnotations({ intent: 'display' })
                .then(function(annotations) {

                    PDFJS.AnnotationLayer.render({
                        viewport: viewport.clone({ dontFlip: true }),
                        div: annotationLayerElt,
                        annotations: annotations,
                        page: pdfPage,
                        linkService: linkService,
                        renderInteractiveForms: false
                    });
                });

                var pdfRenderOperation =
                pdfRender.promise
                .then(function() {

                    annotationLayerElt.style.visibility = '';
                    canceling = false;
                    pdfRender = null;
                })
                .catch(function(err) {

                    pdfRender = null;
                    if ( err instanceof PDFJS.RenderingCancelledException ) {

                        canceling = false;
                        this.renderPage(rotate);
                        return;
                    }
                    emitEvent('error', err);
                }.bind(this))

                return Promise.all([getAnnotationsOperation, pdfRenderOperation]);
            }.bind(this));
        }


        this.forEachPage = function(pageCallback) {

            var numPages = pdfDoc.numPages;

            (function next(pageNum) {

                pdfDoc.getPage(pageNum)
                .then(pageCallback)
                .then(function() {

                    if ( ++pageNum <= numPages )
                        next(pageNum);
                })
            })(1);
        }


        this.loadPage = function(pageNumber, rotate) {

            pdfPage = null;

            if ( pdfDoc === null )
                return;

            pendingOperation = pendingOperation.then(function() {

                return pdfDoc.getPage(pageNumber);
            })
            .then(function(page) {

                pdfPage = page;
                this.renderPage(rotate);
                emitEvent('page-loaded', page.pageNumber);
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(function(err) {

                clearCanvas();
                clearAnnotations();
                emitEvent('error', err);
            });
        }

        this.loadDocument = function(src) {

            pdfDoc = null;
            pdfPage = null;

            emitEvent('num-pages', undefined);

            if ( !src ) {

                canvasElt.removeAttribute('width');
                canvasElt.removeAttribute('height');
                clearAnnotations();
                return;
            }

            // wait for pending operation ends
            pendingOperation = pendingOperation.then(function() {

                var loadingTask;
                if ( isPDFDocumentLoadingTask(src) ) {

                    if ( src.destroyed ) {

                        emitEvent('error', new Error('loadingTask has been destroyed'));
                        return
                    }

                    loadingTask = src;
                } else {

                    loadingTask = createLoadingTask(src, {
                        onPassword: function(updatePassword, reason) {

                            var reasonStr;
                            switch (reason) {
                                case PDFJS.PasswordResponses.NEED_PASSWORD:
                                    reasonStr = 'NEED_PASSWORD';
                                    break;
                                case PDFJS.PasswordResponses.INCORRECT_PASSWORD:
                                    reasonStr = 'INCORRECT_PASSWORD';
                                    break;
                            }
                            emitEvent('password', updatePassword, reasonStr);
                        },
                        onProgress: function(status) {

                            var ratio = status.loaded / status.total;
                            emitEvent('progress', Math.min(ratio, 1));
                        }
                    });
                }

                return loadingTask.promise;
            })
            .then(function(pdf) {

                pdfDoc = pdf;
                emitEvent('num-pages', pdf.numPages);
                emitEvent('loaded');
            })
            .catch(function(err) {

                clearCanvas();
                clearAnnotations();
                emitEvent('error', err);
            })
        }

        annotationLayerElt.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
    }

    return {
        createLoadingTask: createLoadingTask,
        PDFJSWrapper: PDFJSWrapper,
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked so well ! thank you so much for your answer it was really so helpful.